# i want to print all armstrong number between 1 to 1000 in a textbox using awt or swing but i only get last value by my code .So plc help me

Tags: java, swing, awt

i want to print all armstrong number between 1 to 1000 in a textfield using awt or swing but i only get last value by my code .So pls help me

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String s1=tf.getText();
        int n1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
        for(int n=0;n<10000;n++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            int number=n;
            int original=number;
            while(number>0)
            {
            int r=number%10;
            sum+=r*r*r;
            number=number/10;
            }
            if(sum==original)
            {
                tf1.setText(String.valueOf(original[i]));

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't know, an Armstrong number (or narcissistic number) is a number with n digits that is equal to the sum of each of its digits to the nth power.

(x<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>(n-1)</sup>)+(x<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>(n-2)</sup>)...+(x<sub>1</sub>*10<sup>(n-n)</sup>) = (x<sub>1</sub>)<sup>n</sup>+(x<sub>2</sub>)<sup>n</sup>...+(x<sub>n</sub>)<sup>n</sup>

This means that if the number is 1 digit, the power will be `1`.

Therefore there are 10 1 digit numbers that are Armstrong numbers:

1. 0 = 0<sup>1</sup>
2. 1 = 1<sup>1</sup>
3. 2 = 2<sup>1</sup>
4. 3 = 3<sup>1</sup>
5. 4 = 4<sup>1</sup>
6. 5 = 5<sup>1</sup>
7. 6 = 6<sup>1</sup>
8. 7 = 7<sup>1</sup>
9. 8 = 8<sup>1</sup>
10. 9 = 9<sup>1</sup>

Your code, as written, will not identify any of those numbers as Armstrong numbers.

Your code will also incorrectly identify some numbers as 4 digit Armstrong numbers because you only look for the the cubes (3rd power) of your numbers not the 4th power.
<sub>(You don't have to worry about twos because there are no two digit Armstrong numbers)</sub>

---

In order to correctly determine all the possible Armstrong numbers between 1 and 10000, you need to write a "power" loop that finds the nth power of a number by multiplying the number `n` times.

This would look something like:

```
//... beginning of your original function
//added a string to hold all the values before printing
string holder = "";
for(int n=0;n<10000;n++){
  int sum=0;
    //n=original you had duplicate variables (just use n as original)
  int number = n;
    //while there are still digits left
  while(number>0){
      //get the smallest digit
    int r=number%10;
      //----------"Power" loop-----------
    int foo = n;
      //once smaller than 10, it's only a power of 1 (which is itself)
    while(foo>=10){
        //this means foo = foo/10
      foo /= 10;
        //this means r = r*r
      r*=r;
    }
      //this means sum = sum+r
    sum += r;
      //you should have the hang of it by now
    number/=10;
  }
    //if the sum equals the original number
  if(sum==n){
      //put that number into the end of a string (separated by newlines `\n`)
    holder+=n+"\n";
  }
}
  //All done, so set the text box value
tf1.setText(holder);
//... whatever code you want to finish up
```

This should also take care of your problem with the textBox getting overwritten each time. By saving the numbers into a string and then printing all of them at once, only once (no overwriting), you'll get better results.

Answer (score 0):

You always set the current found value. But you should set the previous found values + current found value.

```
 tf1.setText(String.valueOf(original));
```

But more performant would be to use a stringbuilder object and append the result each time and set this value to the textfield outside the loop.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{


    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder ();


    for(int n=0;n<10000;n++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int number=n;
        int original=number;
        while(number>0)
        {
        int r=number%10;
        sum+=r*r*r;
        number=number/10;
        }
        if(sum==original)
        {
            s.append(original + " ");
        }
    }
    tf1.setText (stringBuilder.toString ());    
}
```

Comment: 'i'  ? From where you got it ?

Comment: @anptk I think Juru meant `n`.

Comment: I was in the original post. Just copy pasted it. Edited.

Comment: Mind that your algorithm is functionally incorrect. Check out the other answer of @Enigmadan for this. My answer only fixes your output of multiple numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, all you do is change the `setText()` method of the `TextField1` component with `append()`.
It works! The remaining will do! Try it once.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String s1=tf.getText();
    int n1=Integer.parseInt(s1);
    for(int n=0;n<10000;n++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        int number=n;
        int original=number;
        while(number>0)
        {
        int r=number%10;
        sum+=r*r*r;
        number=number/10;
        }
        if(sum==original)
        {
            tf1.append(String.valueOf(original[i] + " "));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple program in `C` to list all armstrong number between 1 to 1000000.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
main()
{
    long a = 1, c=0, b, e, f, d = 0,g=0,p,j,count=0;

    printf("All armstron number between 1 and 1000000 is listed below!\n");
    while (c <= 1000000)
    {
        j = c;
        if (j >= 10)
        {
            while (j >= 10)
            {
                j = j / 10;
                g++;
            }
        }
        p = g + 1;
        g = 0;
        a = c;
        f = a;
        while (a >= 10)
        {
            b = a % 10;
            d = d + pow(b,p);

            a = a / 10;
        }
        e = pow(a,p) + d;       
        d = 0;
        if (e == f)
        {
            count++;
            printf("%ld\t",count );
            printf("%ld\n", f);
        }
        c++;
    }
    getch();
}
```